# Open source framework à la Microsoft Sync Framework suggestions?

Tags: database, open-source, mobile, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

We are implementing a warehouse management system atop an open source stack (Java, web services & friends). In this system, we want to integrate many mobile devices which should also be capable of adequate online/offline functionality, e.g. preparing database inserts while a mobile device is temporarily unconnected, and performing them on the backend database when reconnected.

For a .NET stack, Microsoft Sync Framework would be a perfect solution, e.g. to do database replication and hoarding. **Can anyone suggest an open source alternative to the MS Sync Framework and possibly describe his experiences with it? Thanks in advance for any answers.**

Comment: What these mobile devices would be running? Is it possible to choose?

Comment: actually have you considered using a part of your application on .net using sync framework? It might be worth the pain in integration, because sync framework is becoming very mature now with some nice features like batching support.

Answer (score 3):

This is a great question. One of the most mature solutions for Sync is Sybase iAnywhere's MobiLink. We have used it extensively, and it is perfect for enterprise systems if you have some budget. It is not open source, and so does not meet your requirements as stated.

You could mix some basic web technologies to roll your own, which is where we are heading. Simple web services and HTML 5 for the offline content and database storage. See this link:

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/offline.html - Offline Browser Applications

http://webkit.org/blog/126/webkit-does-html5-client-side-database-storage/ - Client Database Storage

Check out this example: http://webkit.org/demos/sticky-notes/

I have seen talk of Open Database Sync, but nothing concrete.

Answer (score 1):

Herbert:

I would like to invite you to check out [OpenMobster](http://openmobster.googlecode.com). It is an Open Source Cloud Platform for Mobile Apps. It uses the business friendly Eclipse license.

Features include:

```
* Platform for developing Sync based Mobile Apps 

* Platform for developing Push based Mobile Apps 

* Platform for developing Offline Mobile Apps 

* Frameworks for App development 

* Server Side Frameworks for mobilizing Cloud Services 

* Management Console
```

Sync is specifically designed for apps requiring offline capabilities. All sync modes such as Two-Way Sync, One Way Device Sync, One Way Cloud Sync, Boot Sync (an innovation over Slow Sync) is supported.

The Cloud Side is Java based running on a JBoss Microcontainer based kernel.

2.0 which is in Beta supports all Android versions and BlackBerry 4.0.x.

2.2 will add support for iPhone and a GWT based Management Console among other features.

Here are some links that may help you get more information:
link://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/AndroidSyncApp, and link://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/DeveloperZone

If you have more questions, please feel free to post on the user forum at:
link://groups.google.com/group/openmobster-users

Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see [SymmetricDS](http://symmetricds.codehaus.org/) listed yet. It is an open source (LGPL) Java-based database synchronization system. It is under active development and has been around for a while. It is similar in many ways to Microsoft's Sync Framework. One difference is that it will auto-create the triggers it needs to capture the data. I seriously considered using this for my next project, but we are a Microsoft shop and will probably go with MSF.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much information out there, but "Sync" seems to be Javas answer to the MS Synchronization Framework.

There's an interesting paper here - http://www.cs.unc.edu/~dewan/sync/sync_paper.html, and some not so useful information on the IBM site - http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iwedhelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2e.doc%2Fsynfjsa.html.